# How can I insert macrons into a UTF-8 MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have letters with macrons such as `ū`, which I would like to store in a **MySQL MyISAM** table. The table is set to `UTF-8` with `utf8_swedish_ci collation`. However, no matter what I do, the character is replaced by a question mark.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Used Sequel Pro to edit the row in which one of the fields contains the macron, and to enter the query manually. (Result: '?')
- Changed `collation` to `unicode`, general, and bin, respectively. (Result: either '?' or that the row can't even be saved.)
- Used the terminal (OS X, bash, set to UTF-8) to enter the query manually. (Result: '?')
- Tried using PHP, since the table is going to be part by a web app. PHP recognizes the character just fine if, for instance, I save the script in `UTF-8` encoding and use regular expressions on it - but it still can't save it to the table. (Result: '?')

I could save it as `&#363;` instead, but I'd rather not if possible. Any help greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: If you have utf-8 allt he way, it should just work. However, there are a few things to look at carefully: is the query you are _storing_ the value with written in utf-8? Is the _column_ utf-8 (which could be other then the tables default)? Are you setting your _connection_ character set tu utf-8? [see also this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/358679)

Comment: .. and also, are you actually inserting UTF-8, or has the character accidentally been regressed to a question mark in an earlier stage?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I didn't realise columns could be in other charsets as well - everything else was UTF-8 all the way down. Wrikken, if you'd like to change your comment into an answer, I would be happy to accept it.